# Есть ли слово "едь"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Попалась как-то вот такая картинка:

[image]

Так вот, все в комментариях стали обсуждать тот факт, что слова "едь" в русском языке нет. А есть "езжай". Но я сомневаюсь в том, правы ли комментирующие. Действительно ли в русском языке нет слова "едь" и "поедь", а есть только "езжай" и "поезжай" или же первый вариант - просто разговорный?